# CodeIgniter and mariaDB

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, xampp, mariadb

I have a site that was developed in CODEIGNITER and MYSQL, now I want to change MYSQL to MARIA DB so that I can run it on XAMPP local host, what can I do to get the site running on MARIA DB at back end?

Comment: Have you tried the sql dump export-import. I don't think there is any huge difference between both databases.

Comment: I did, but no use. All I know is that MARIA DB is fork of MYSQL. @kishor10d

Comment: "no use" -- explain.

Comment: I meant, the problem was still occurring, the same problem, but now everything is solved. But thanks anyways @RickJames

Comment: Try to update your $db['default'] array in database.php with 'port' => 3307 ... As MariaDB uses port 3307.